# TimePicker bug in ScrollView Xamarin.Forms version 4.4.0.991477

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**BUG REPORT of Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0.991477**
I have updated my Xamarin.Forms version to the latest of it which is the `4.4.0.991477`, the reason is that I need it to use the preview control of `SwipeView` in my xamarin.forms application, the problem was that the **TimePicker control has errors inside ScrollView** in the current version, is there already a solution for this bug or its still?

Comment: this is not the forum for filing bug reports, and "has errors" is not a useful description of the problem.  https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: I test TimePicker inside the ScrollView in Xamarin.Forms 4.4.0.991477,  I can running normally.Here is running GIF. https://imgur.com/a/eM5tzUn, Note: you cannot put the TimePicker  in the `SwipeView`, If you put it, you cannot click the TimePicker , If you insist on that is a bug, you can report this bug in Github: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues, do not forget to post a demo that could reproduce this issue.